# get_the_post_thumbnail_url('full') returns empty from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails, thumbnails, post-type

I'm trying to display the full size image of the single post from a custom post type that I created, below is what I've tried

```
<?php
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'press',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => false
    );
$press = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $press->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <?php while ( $press->have_posts() ) : $press->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4 mb24">
        <article class="post-article bg-white">
            <div class="article-img">
                <?php
                if( has_post_thumbnail() ){
                ?>
                <div class="img-box position-relative overflow-hidden">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="height300 bg-graylight flex-center c-dark position-relative">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="height300 bg-graylight flex-center c-dark position-relative">
                    <i class="ti-image font64"></i>
                </a>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

but seems this

```
get_the_post_thumbnail_url('full')
```

not working because it shows nothing e.g. `src=""` but if I do

```
get_the_post_thumbnail_url()
```

surely gives me the image url but not the full size one. Any help, ideas please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument for that function is not size. See [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) (if a function's not working, checking the documentation should always be your first step):

```
get_the_post_thumbnail_url( int|WP_Post $post = null, string|array $size = 'post-thumbnail' )
```

The first argument is which post the get the URL for, while the size is the *second* argument.

To avoid redundancy, when you're in the loop, set the first argument to `null` to get the current post:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( null, 'full' ); ?>
```

But honestly, you shouldn't be using this function this way. If you want to output the post thumbnail, use the `the_post_thumbnail()` function. That way you automatically get the image's `alt` text, `width` and `height` attributes, as well as `srcset` and sizes:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="height300 bg-graylight flex-center c-dark position-relative">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?>
</a>
```